# Hiding <div> from vb.net code side

Tags: html, vb.net, css-tables

I have this code for hiding a table and a cell in aspx, backend vb.net.
Code -

```
For Each row As HtmlTableRow In tab_a1.Rows
                    If row.ID = "a1" Then
                        For Each cell As HtmlTableCell In row.Cells
                            cell.Visible = (cell.ID = "a1")
                        Next
                    ElseIf row.ID = "b1" Then
                        For Each cell As HtmlTableCell In row.Cells
                            cell.Visible = (cell.ID = "b1")
                        Next
                    Else
                        row.Visible = False
                    End If
                Next
```

Now instead of tables I'm using `<div>` tags. How can I use similar code and make div's visible and invisible?

Answer (score 12):

Add `runat="server"` and an ID to your div. You can then hide the div using its `Visible` property.

Markup:

```
<div ID="myDiv" runat="server">Test DIV</div>
```

VB:

```
myDiv.Visible = False 'Hide the div.
myDiv.Visible = True 'Show the div.
```

You can loop through child controls using the controls collection:

```
For Each child As Control In myDiv.Controls
    If TypeOf child Is HtmlControl Then
        Dim typedChild As HtmlControl = CType(child, HtmlControl)
        'Search grandchildren, toggle visibility, etc.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: but i have 50 div's nested in each other so i need to loop through them

Comment: @reffe I've added a description of looping through the Div's child collection.